# Cannot set PubNub auth key Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

I have a webapp and the iOS app built in Swift. The thing is I don't know Swift and I'm trying to modify the iOS app in order to add the authorization key to the PubNub client before subscribing/publishing to channels.
[Link to PubNub docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/api-reference-configuration#auth)

PRE:

- Access Manager is enabled
- `my_auth_key` is hardcoded and already enabled form the server for the corresponding channel I want to subscribe.

[Here is the code](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/598bf07199e8551f77d64bfa)

What's the correct way to set the auth key?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi I am also creating demo for ios, but unable to set PAM. After research, I come to know that I can achieve this using function, But not able to understand how it will be achieved. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polak, mentioned docs code snippet refer to previously created instance to get it's pre-configured PNConfiguration instance and change required field. This practice can be used in case if you need change something at run-time. 
If you have data for `authKey` at the moment of client initialization, you can set it:

```
var pubnubClient: PubNub = {
    let configuration = PNConfiguration(publishKey: UCConstants.PubNub.publishKey, subscribeKey: UCConstants.PubNub.subscribeKey)
    configuration.authKey = "my_auth_key"
    return PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(configuration)
}()
```

Also, I've tried exact your code and don't have any issues with setting of `authKey`, because I can see it with subscribe request.
If you still will have troubles with PAM and auth key usage, please contact us on support@pubnub.com

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can:

```
let configuration = PNConfiguration(
    authKey: "super_secret",
    publishKey: UCConstants.PubNub.publishKey,
    subscribeKey: UCConstants.PubNub.subscribeKey
)
```

Based on the Obj-C code: https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/blob/8c1f0876b5b34176f33681d22844e8d763019635/PubNub/Data/PNConfiguration.m#L174-L181

Comment: please look into it and help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889108/how-to-implement-pubnub-access-manager-in-swift