# How to implement Pubnub Access Manager in swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, pubnub

I am doing R&D on how to implement a pubnub access manager in swift, and after some research, I come to know :

- Swift SDK does not include pubnub.grant
- I need to achieve this using a pubnub function for serverless computing

> I have created one function in the pubnub dashboard and created a
>   module PubNub, also created a function with event type "On Request"
>   and added code of grant.

```
  export default (request, response) => {
    const pubnub = require('pubnub');
    const kvstore = require('kvstore');

    let headersObject = request.headers;
    let paramsObject = request.params;
    let methodString = request.method;
    let bodyString = request.body;

    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

    var uuid = 'aartisagarvadgama'

    return pubnub.grant({
        channels: ['channel_atts_pubnub'],
        read: true, // false to disallow
        write: false, // false to disallow,
        authKeys: [uuid],
        ttl: 0
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('grant success')
        response.status = 200;
      return response.send(uuid);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        response.status = 400;
        return response.send();
    });
};
```

I am calling this above function by copying URL from function and getting success code, But how this can reflect my iOS application.

**Please let me know anyway by which I can achieve the access manager in my app.**

> As per my understanding, I need to create a function and by calling
>   that function I can grant the user. After that When I will try to
>   subscribe or publish, I will get 200 instead of 403. Any help will be
>   appreciated.  Please help me.

Comment: @StephenBlum please look into it and help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889108/how-to-implement-pubnub-access-manager-in-swift

Comment: Swift SDK does not have `grant` method because you need to init PubNub with your secret key and you should never do so in a client application. You should only do so in a secure server. Your server grants permissions to an auth-key that is passed back to your clients, like a Swift app, and that auth-key is used to init PubNub with your subscribe key and optionally your publish key.

Comment: @CraigConover Thank you for your reply. Can you please let me know that Is it achievable using PubNub Functions? How can I do that? Please check I have updated my question

Comment: @CraigConover I have created a function in my dashboard. And calling it. But still getting 403 in my app. My concern is how this function can reflect my app, so I can receive 200 instead of 403.

Comment: Can you send request to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and reference this Stack Overflow link so we can answer back when it is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Access Manager for Swift Apps

The [PubNub Swift SDK (Access Manager Tutorial)](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pam-security) does not have grant method because you need to init PubNub with your secret key and you should never do so in a client application. You should only do so in a secure server. Your server grants permissions to an auth-key that is passed back to your clients, like a Swift app, and that auth-key is used to init PubNub with your subscribe key and optionally your publish key.

#### See Also

- [Access Manager Getting Started Guide](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/getting-started-guides/pubnub-access-manager)
- [PubNub Access Manager - How It Works](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tech/security/access-manager/)
- [Node SDK Docs - Security with Access Manager Tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pam-security)